# Rails, getting a part of a URL /modelstuff/31 --- how to get 31?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm interested in learning in Rails 3, how to grab the URL with something like `params[:urlpath]`

and then indexing it with /

so if I had a url like examples:

```
/books/1
/books/1/authors/3
/books/1/authors/3/chapters
/books/1/authors/3/chapters/33
```

I could always obtain 1

something like `params[:urlpath] index[2]`

I need this to populate the following which is happening on the page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/nav/sidenav',
    data: "urlpath=" + urlpath
});
```

ideas? thxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your routes.rb:

```
match '/modelstuff/:id' => "controller#method"
```

Then you can use `params[:id]`

Comment: I'm making an AJAX call to get a sub navigation via /nav/sidenav and I need to know the current page's URL to know how to populate nav/sidenav properly, which is why params[:id] doesn't work in this situation but I believe I need the sidenav to determine the ID.. Thoughts?

Comment: @WozPoz - You should take a look at the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) on Routing and requests

Comment: @WozPoz - Because it provides info on various ways to do what you want.

Comment: ok added the AJAX call above to help clear out the use case. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If your URLs look like `/books/1/authors/3/chapters/33`

Then your routes should be:

```
resources :books do 
  resources :authors do
    resources :chapters
  end
end
```

This is called Nested Routes.

Then, in your controller:

/app/controllers/chapters_controller.rb

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @author = @book.authors.find(params[:author_id])
  @chapter = @author.chapters.find(params[:id])
end
```

Sort of magic.

Comment: Very cool. But in the case mentioned above I'm not calling the chapters_controller. I'm calling app/controllers/navs

Comment: Then your url should look like /nav?book_id=1&author_id=3&chapter_id=33